# ProgressDialog onCreate

Tags: android, progressdialog, oncreate

In "onCreate" I'm downloading data from web.The duration of downloading data is 10 sec. I wan't to have ProgressDialog while the data is downloading. Here is my code , but the ProgressDialog doesn't appear:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Test.this, "", 
        "Loading. Please wait...", true);

     try {
         URL myURL = new URL("http://www.sample.com/");
         URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
         InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
         ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
         int current = 0;
          while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                  baf.append((byte)current);
          }

          content= new String(baf.toByteArray());

     }
     catch (Exception e) {}
     dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to do this kind of things is using `AsyncTask` in order to not freeze the application while you are downloading the file. Moreover, what if you give your users a better experience by using a progress bar dialog rather than a simple dialog. It's not difficult to implement; you can see an example here: [**Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog/3028660#3028660)

Comment: Thank you this is great. But in my case i shouldn't use class that extends form AsyncTask, I need to use which extends from Activity. Can I do that to not freeze my app with activity extends? I need only simple dialog without progressbar . Thanks

Comment: Of course! You will always need an `Activity`. In this case, the class that extends `AsyncTask` is a private class inside your activity. In the example I didn't write the activity code to focus on what's important in this case: the `AsyncTask`

Comment: make another class extending AsyncTask<> and call it using new asyncTaskClass().execute();, in onPreExecute, show Progressdialog and hide it on onPostExecute