# Easiest way to implement visual-feedback/busy-indicator in android

Tags: android

I am creating an app `MainActivity` that can calculate a report from its database to be shown in `ReportActivity`. All report calculation is done in `ReportActivity.onCreate()`.

When the user click on MainActivity-s menu "generate report" the menü remains open for 2 secs until  `ReportActivity.onCreate()` has finished and the report becomes visible.

What is the easiest way to give the user some visual feedback?

I already found [ProgressDialog onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122465/progressdialog-oncreate) that shows a progressdialog while doing all calculation in an AsyncTask.

I wonder if there is some easier way to give the user some visual feedbak that the menue was successfully clicked and that the device has not crashed.

in ms windows i would use a waitcursor (hour-glass)

I already tried to open a ProgressDialog() in oncreate of the ReportActivity

```
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "MY Dialog", "Please wait...");
```

but it is not shown at all.

**Update** final solution:

As the answerss suggested I implemented an AsyncTask for the processing following [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog/3028660) 
based on [this codesample](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/10/android-download-file-with-progress-bar.html)

Comment: ANR timelimit is 5 sec, how your application take 10 sec for generating report without an ANR.

Comment: you are right it felt like 10 secs- actually it was only 1-2 secs. I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your long-running code into a background thread. Long-running code on the UI thread will lock up the UI, which causes the user to think the app is frozen/crashing. Look into using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This allows you to run a process on a background thread and also give visual feedback to let the user know that your app is working.

Answer (score 1):

Design a layout with ProgressDialog. Use setContentView(Progressdialog). Count time for 2-4 seconds (you choice) again set your older layout in setContentView. Why don't you use AsyncTask?

Answer (score 1):

Use a bar or circle activity indicator. From [the official design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html):

> Activity indicators are for operations of an indeterminate length.
>   They ask users to wait a moment while something finishes up, without
>   getting into specifics about what's happening behind the scenes.